# Choice in flow not accepting selection

Tags: visual-workflow, fields

I have a very simple flow - it shows contacts filtered by one field.
The dynamic choice is displayed using radio buttons (drop down shows the same behaviour). When I choose an option and click on next, a message appears "Please select a choice".
If I filter by different fields, sometimes it works as expected, sometimes it doesn't. On different sandboxes filtering by that particular field works, not on others.

This seems to be an issue with the particular field, but I cannot see any difference between fields or sandboxes.

All fields used are definitely visible by me - filter field, id and label field.

Is there anything on the field definition that might cause this issue?

The flow in all its simplicity - I cannot see anything that I might change in order to correct this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Addendum: the filter above returns 10 results:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging and support from an SF employee, I have an answer now.

The search works over a data set of 3.2 million contacts. When selecting the option, an exception is thrown:

```
EXCEPTION_THROWN [EXTERNAL]|System.QueryException: Non-selective query 
against large object type (more than 200000 rows). Consider an indexed
filter or contact salesforce.com about custom indexing.
```

This exception can be seen if the log level is adjusted (I usually only have Apex logging on a high setting).

It's currently unknown why that happens in that stage, but a solution is to have all fields that contribute to the filter to be indexed.

The fields I used for testing when it worked were indexed, but in this case ssn__c was not. The issue is not related to the amount of data returned by the original filter, but to the amount of entries in the database.